# Building AOSP project with gradle build application

Tags: android, gradle, android-source

I am developing android AOSP project with my custom app. Everything was working great until I try to update gradle version from 2.14 to 4.4. 
I have following Android.mk file that is working with gradle 2.14 but not with gradle 4.4:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyAndroidApp
LOCAL_MODULE := MyAndroidApp
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional


LOCAL_APK_FILE := app/build/outputs/apk/MyAndroidApp.apk

$(info $(shell cd external/MyAndroidApp/;JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ ./gradlew assembleDebug >&2))
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_APK_FILE)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

My AOSP project uses old android version so it have to be build with Java 6 so I have to modify Android.mk file to use newer java version which is required by gradle 4, bu this version of Android.mk works with application using gradle 4.4.

When I am trying to build my project I got error:

```
       File 'out/target/product/myProject/obj/APPS/MyAndroidApp_intermediates/MyAndroidApp.apk' does not exist.
      Must remake target 'out/target/product/myProject/obj/APPS/MyAndroidApp_intermediates/MyAndroidApp.apk'.
target Prebuilt APK: MyAndroidApp (out/target/product/myProject/obj/APPS/MyAndroidApp_intermediates/MyAndroidApp.apk)
make: *** [out/target/product/myProject/obj/APPS/MyAndroidApp_intermediates/MyAndroidApp.apk] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'out/target/product/myProject/obj/APPS/MyAndroidApp_intermediates/MyAndroidApp.apk'
```

Does anyone have any suggestion? Maybe my Andoid.mk should be different? But... it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can separate gradle application, and built apk for it. And then create a project in `AOSP` and use `Android.mk` to build your apk file, which will avoid to build your gradle application in `Android.mk`. Although it's stupid and simple, it works great in my work.

Comment: It is not the problem with gradle in Android.mk - app builds correctly. But for simplify I build app outside Android.mk. So I remove from Android.mk that line with gradle, LOCAL_APK_FILE point to apk and when it is build with gradle 2.14 then everything works fine, but AOSP build fail when LOCAL_APK_FILE point to apk built with gradle 4.4

Comment: Maybe you can try `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.